# VB.Net running as a service

Tags: vb.net, service, application-types

I have built an application that connects to the exchange server and does some scanning tasks on the incoming mail.

Application has a form where i can start and stop scanning,give in an interval, do some other configuration, and a notificationicon in the taskbar to show hide,end and so on..

The problem is that I would like the application to start as a service, because now a user has to log in first on the server before it starts working.

I tried some tools like RunAsService, i had a service, but obviously it didn't run the application.

Of course i understeand now that when the application will run as a service, scanning will be the only thing that will happen, no forms and no notification icons.

However i do not know where to start, should i extract the scanning logic from my configuration  as a separate application? What application type should it become then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two easy options.

First one just create a new Windows Service Project from your **New Project** button in the Visual Studio, and then just program your app.

Second one, just create a service from the service management window in your computer and add the executable file of your program. It will start running as a service (with visible windows and everything as you coded it).

Comment: Couple of links i found http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/ http://tools.sysprogs.org/srvman/

Comment: Thanks for correcting me,i agree this type of edits should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows7/schedule-a-task) and schedule your vb.net windows program as windows task

In Your code, at the end ,when everything gets executed you should write `Me.Close()` to hide your form.

Comment: A good temporary solution, thank you! Temporary, becouse this will not create a service, and I would really like to know how to program a service, not only for this project, but to learn it also for the future.